# Editing uploaded PDF file using PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, file-upload

I have a js script which enables us to annotate a pdf page.
How do I save that file after editing (adding annotations to) it?

Correct me if I am wrong:
When we upload a file from client system,

- the file is stored in a temp location
- we get the path of the temp location and use it to render the PDF

After we edit (annotate), these changes don't resonate in the PDF file stored in temp location?
How do I apply these changes to the file stored in temp location in server?

Comment: Exactly my point. As i have mentioned i have a javascript which can edit the file after it is rendered(all this is happening on the website). How to save the file along with the changes using php.

Comment: sorry my bad, I misunderstood

Comment: please help me with this.

Comment: Sorry man, I'm still unexperienced myself, only been in this for 3years and haven't learnt anything new in a while, thanks to my current job. you'll have to wait for someone with higher rep / more experience

Comment: I have been in this only for a month now and they gave me this task.

Comment: I'd be happy man, you're learning quickly! that adds to your value as a developer, when I started out I did google maps, fql and facebook connect, mvc, a lot of things. . .I got paid $250 a month for that year, but up till today I couldn't thank that boss enough for the experience it added to my portfolio

Comment: you seem to know a lot about webdevelopment. Could you share your email so i can contact you if i need any assistance. I need assistance for my upcoming projects.

Comment: wow, that would be too much man, add me on linkedIn, the messages come straight to my email; za.linkedin.com/pub/abdul-baasit-ismail/21/557/a02/

Answer (score 0):

You should not add changes to the temporary PHP file, because it is deleted after your script ended. Hence you must save the temp file and your annotation to another location.

Comment: "The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed." see http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: ok lets say I moved it away and accesed it again through URL .As i have mentioned i have a javascript which can edit the file after it is rendered(all this is happening on the website). How to save the file along with the changes( using php.).

Comment: I get that file will be deleted after end of request.

Comment: My question is once we retrieve the file from server we are basically copying the file. I can edit the file on the website using Javascript. How to save these changes to file in the sever.

Comment: What kind of data is uploaded to the server via JavaScript? An PDF (e.g. octet-stream) or just some kind of meta data (e.g. page number and annotation class)?